# Are there terminal emulators that support bi-directional text?

Tags: unicode, terminal-emulator

I tried searching for this but came out empty-handed. Is it possible for me to get my terminal emulator to display right-to-left Unicode grapheme clusters properly?

Use case: I'm writing a script that outputs Arabic letters to the terminal and it's currently outputting the glyphs in reverse order, which messes up the way they're supposed to connect, making them visually difficult to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't used it as I don't speak Arabic, but this gets decent reviews: http://mlterm.sourceforge.net/

See also:

[A Quick Primer on Unicode and Software Internationalization under Linux and Unix](http://eyegene.ophthy.med.umich.edu/unicode/).

Comment: see also http://eyegene.ophthy.med.umich.edu/unicode/

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. I added the link provided by @StephaneChazelas to the answer because it's really useful. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 4):

konsole does and supports bidirectional writing

Comment: I just tried it and it does. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Yes but not ZWJ grapheme cluster.

Answer (score 2):

konsole supports it as built-in, BUT on other terminal emulators, you need to install [BiCon](https://github.com/behdad/bicon) (bidirectional console).

Answer (score 1):

GNOME Terminal version 3.34 supports right to left scripts, and so do other VTE-based emulators (e.g. Tilix, Terminator, Xfce Terminal, Guake...) if using VTE version 0.58.