# How to make Arabic appear properly in linux terminal?

Tags: linux-mint

In Linux Mint 13, when using the Arabic language, text is shown backwards.

I found a [possible answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77657/how-to-enable-arabic-support-in-gnome-terminal) that says I should do:

```
sudo apt-get install libfribidi0 libfribidi-dev
```

then install bicon, and then put

```
Terminal=true
Exec=/usr/bin/bicon.bin
```

in `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`.

After doing this, I restart my computer and enter terminal, but my language is still shown backwards, so then I type in `bicon` and it fix it.

How can I make terminal work properly without having to type `bicon` every time?

Comment: If the possible answer was http://askubuntu.com/questions/77657/how-to-enable-arabic-support-in-gnome-terminal, you could comment there, and try any solutions suggested in the launchpad bug too.

Comment: When you say "terminal", do you mean Gnome Terminal?  How are you starting it?  By clicking the icon in the Applications menu, or some other way?

Comment: @Mikel yes I start terminal in application menu, also ctrl + alt + t.  Terminal is gnome terminal 3.4.1.1

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + T doesn't work the same way.  Check your Keyboard Settings to see if that runs `gnome-terminal` or `bicon.bin`.  Sounds like it needs to be the second one.

Comment: Does the text look right when you open it from the application menu?

Comment: @Mikel Ctrl + Alt + T open runs gnome terminal.  Where I go to open terminal it open the same, wheter from menu or I go to applications file, it only look right when I open terminal and put in "bicon" or I go to /usr/bin and open bicon from there saying run in terminal.

Comment: Have you seen my [very similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/100811/26909)? The answers there suggest `mlterm` which is superb and also `Konsole` which is the default terminal emulator in the KDE environment. I have tried both and they work flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

here is a hack I use to make it work.
add the folowing to your `.bashrc` file.

```bsh
# hack to launch bicon if not launched
if ! [[ "$(ps -p $(ps -p $(echo $$) -o ppid=) -o comm=)" =~ 'bicon'* ]]; then
  bicon.bin
fi
```

this should also work for new tab.
strange behavior happens when you try to open bash inside bash, don't do that.

Comment: the solution had been enhanced too :) http://bluemix2.blogspot.com/2015/08/linux-terminal-support-for-gnome-316.html

Comment: Warning: this caused my Gnome 3.16.2 gdm to freeze or failed to start after login!

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Terminal version 3.34 supports right to left scripts such as Arabic, and so do other VTE-based emulators (e.g. Tilix, Terminator, Xfce Terminal, Guake...) if using VTE version 0.58. No need to use bicon anymore.